# Karate matcher to validate embeded arrays in response

Tags: karate, matcher, web-api-testing

I have an api response in below format

```
[ 
   { 
     primaryItem: ' some non null string' , 
     secondaryItems: [
         {
             property_1: 'non Null String',
             property_2: 'non null String'
         },
         .......,
         ........
      ]  
   },
   .......,
   ........
   
]
```

I want to write a match expression to validate only the structure of data, not the content of data.

I wrote the matcher like below and it works

```
 ....
 ....
 When method GET
 Then status 200
 And match response != null
 And match each response contains { primaryItem: '#string', secondaryItems: '#array'}
```

But if I want to validate each `secondaryItems` structure, what is the best way to do it ?

### UPDATE

I believe solution is already documented in  [karate-schema-validation](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#schema-validation).

Comment: that's right, I'm closing your question as a duplicate. there are many examples: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+array+schema